# chi squared test for data observed and theoretical between 0 and 1

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I am doing some data analysis for a project and need to make a fit of the data to a line using least squares. Then i need to evaluate the goodness of fit of my data to this line using chi squared.

The problem is my data is between 0 and 1 and very small (the smallest point in my data set is on the order 10^-6 and the largest is 10^-3). So when i do chi squared on it the value always ends up being super small, which makes me skeptical.

Does chi-squared only work for data that is integers (so when you square it it is always a positive integer or zero)? How do i evaluate the goodness of fit for my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't give sufficient detail to guess for certain exactly what you did, but I suppose you're taking $\sum_i (O_i-E_i)^2/E_i$.

That's for *count data*; for example it's suitable for Poisson counts, where $\text{Var}(O_i)=E_i$. It's also suitable for multnomial counts, where $\text{Var}(O_i)<E_i$, but there's dependence among the $O_i-E_i$ values, and dividing by $E_i$ takes it back to asymptotic chisquare with reduced degrees of freedom.

---

In other circumstances, if $y_i$ is approximately $N(\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)$, and the $y$-values are independent, then $\sum_i Z_i^2$ where $Z_i=\frac{y_i-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}$ should be approximately $\chi^2$ with d.f. equal to the number of terms in the sum. (This corresponds exactly to the Poisson case above; that's a special case of this.)

If your statistic doesn't correspond to something I've mentioned here, you need to say explicitly what you did do.

Comment: this makes sense somewhat, im not very good at stats ,but you are correct with what you assumed i was doing. I was told to do a chi squared test but the data is not counts, its a continuous range (voltage measurements). Is the Z squared number you told me have a name? I am doing the data analysis with python and if it has a name i could potentially find the library for it in scipy or numpy.

Comment: Nevermind, i will just implement it myself. But i am curious what the name of the test is. Also should the sigma be the standard Error or the Standard deviation (my observed values are a mean of 10 samples for each element)?

Comment: It's still called a chi-squared test -- just not one for counts. The standard deviation on the denominator in the z is the standard deviation of the thing in the numerator. So if you have averages in the numerator, is should be the standard error of that average.